# Xamarin Forms portable class library project

Tags: xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

why can't I choose PCL project in options when I create a Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms) ? there is just a Shared Project and .NET Standard, when I previously create a project there was a PCL option.

https://i.imgur.com/KDwty6a.png

Comment: what IDE is this?

Comment: its Visual Studio Community 15.5.2

Comment: I think Portable libs are deprecated; .NET Standard is preferred, easier to work with, why do you want Portable? did you find any issue with .NET Standard?

Comment: Visual Studio 15.4 still had PCLs, 15.5 is the first version that switched to .NET Standard.

Comment: @user8801108 what OS are you using?

Comment: @knotce win 10 Education

Answer (score 1):

When I try to create a PCL in VS 2017 it says *"Class Library (Legacy Portable)*
 and *"This project type has been deprecated. You should use Class library (.NET Standard) instead."*

But if you still want it, xamarin has a guide, you can read about creating a PCL project [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/).